# medoo framework in WP plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-query, framework

Is it ok to use medoo framework (http://medoo.in/) when devloping  new plugin. 
or should I use WP_Query only?

What's right?

Comment: this is like asking if you should eat apples or chicken ;) It depends on the type of meal you want to have.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I'm new in this, and wonder if to start learning WP_Query

Comment: WP_query is central to 90% of things you might want to do in wordpress, not learning it is not realy an option ;)

Answer (score 3):

medoo and other similar libraries are generic, that is they are aimed at querying some database in general and the weight of figuring out necessary queries are on you as developer.

`WP_Query` and other WP APIs that perform requests to database are much more specific. They already contain much of that logic, which allows you to express what you need in API calls, rather than SQL query or abstraction close to it. Related code in core implements *enormous* amount of SQL query generation with literally years of logic and performance optimizations.

Overall for any WP development you *have* to use its APIs as much as possible, or you will have to waste incredible amount of time reinventing what they do.

Though bringing your own database abstraction can certainly be beneficial for some use cases. For example if you plan to develop extension which will add and interact with its own database tables, rather than native WP data structures.